# Excel: Need <a href=""> in if statement to be recognized as string not formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
        +---+------------------+-----------------+---------+
        |   |        A         |        B        |    C    |
        +---+------------------+-----------------+---------+
        | 1 |   Link Reference |   Description   |    ID   |
        +---+------------------+-----------------+---------+
        | 2 |      Result      |    East Quad    |    2    |
        +---+------------------+-----------------+---------+
```

Hey guys,

In Excel, I want to output for cell A2 [Result] the following

```
     <a href="http://www.google.com">East Quad</a>
```

I'm using this formula below.

```
     Result=IF(C2="2","<a href="https://www.google.com">B2</a>,"Null")
```

However, after pressing enter I get an error...

```
     Result=IF(C2="2","<a href=**"https**://www.google.com">B2</a>,"Null")
```

**"https** gets highlighted. I think this is occurring because Excel is interpreting href= as a formula.

I thought maybe adding before it something as TEXT() or STRING() would work, but I wasn't able to get anywhere.

Does anyone know what I could add in order for this error not to prop up, or could it also be a setting within the application that needs to be adjusted?

Thank you!

Comment: One way it to use char(13) which returns double quote char. `=IF(C2="2","<a href="&CHAR(13)&"https://www.google.com"&CHAR(13)&">B2</a>","Null")`

Comment: @yosukesabai    Oh this works too. Thank you. Cool to know this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(C2="2","<a href=""https://www.google.com"">" & B2 & "</a>","Null")
```

[image]

This formula assumes that the cell **C2** contains a *Text* **2** rather than a *Numeric* **2**.

Please note the usage of the double quotes.

Comment: Thank you.. -Face Palm- Such an easy fix. Oh well, now I know more. :D

Comment: @ChunkyFresh  tracking all the double-quotes is very error-prone.

Comment: How so? Funny you say that. I'm actually struggling with adding two cells values to     "<a href=""https://www.google.com/CONCAT(B2," ",C2)"">" & B2 & "</a>"                                                                                                                                                    CONCAT part not working out for me.